# How to give access to LAMP server so that it can execute a ".cgi" or".pl" file which in turn executes a c program which controls a parallel port?

Tags: server, apache2

I have written a `c program` that controls the parallel port ... and also written a `.cgi` file which in turn executes the above `c` program which turns 'on' an led attached to the parallel port.
This thing works fine when i execute the `.cgi` file by giving permissions to execute. But when i try to do the same thing over the localhost(LAMP server) the `.cgi` file is getting called but the `c` program which it should call is not getting executed.
There seems to exist some permissions problem with the web server when trying to access the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Try running a Python CGI server like this in the directory with the executable: `python -m CGIHTTPServer`, and calling it over HTTP. If it works, try switching users to the `www-data` user (`sudo su www-data -`) and try again. If it doesn't work, Python will show errors in the console.

You can try checking what groups your normal users belong to, and which users the `www-data` user belongs to. Most likely, the `www-data` user needs to be added to `dialout` and/or `plugdev`.